# Using !(x-a) instead of x==a in C

Tags: c, performance, memory

I am writing a C program that does many comparisons and I was wondering if this actually saves memory.

Any help appreciated

Comment: It adds confusion, that's it.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The compiler is perfectly capable of minor optimisations of this form, as well as much more sophisticated optimisations.

Comment: Remember of [RulesOfOptimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization)

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to write up both versions and profile each.  Having said that, I'm pretty confident this won't make any difference except make your code harder to read and understand.

Comment: "surprising" results: https://godbolt.org/z/BYsgjS

Comment: Note that if `(x-a)` leads to signed integer arithmetic overflow (big positive `x`, big negative `a`, or vice versa on the signs), then you're invoking undefined behaviour with the arithmetic whereas the behaviour of the comparison is perfectly well defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not. Using a tricky syntax to do something that there's a well-known syntax for is never the right answer. You should use x==a.

Answer (score 5):

Depending upon the types of `x` and `a`, the semantics of `!(x-a)` may be different from those of `x==a`.  Depending upon what one is trying to do, such differences may be helpful, harmful, or irrelevant.  In cases where they are helpful, there should be a comment indicating how the semantics are expected to differ from `x==a`, and why that would be important.

For example, if `x` and `a` are both floating-point values equal to positive infinity, `x==a` would yield 1, but computing `x-a` would yield `NaN`, and applying the `!` operator to that would yield zero.

I am unaware of any common idioms that revolve around differences between `x==a` and `!(a-x)`, so any code which uses the latter form without specifying why should be viewed suspiciously.

Comment: Get an upvote for pointing out that what looks like [novice training for the IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org/) actually could have some subtle differences, depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

`!(x-a)` instead of `x==a`

**`x==a` better**

As pointers `x, a`, `x==a` is well defined. `x-a` is undefined behavior unless `x,a` both point in/near the same object.

As sign integers `x, a`, `x==a` is well defined. `x-a` is may overflow the signed integer range and is then undefined behavior [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119529/using-x-a-instead-of-x-a-in-c#comment95073251_54119529) .

As floating point `x, a`, `x==a` is well defined. `x-a` may have unexpected effects [@supercat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119715/2410359).

**Tie**

With `x` as a pointer within an array and `a` as an `int`, `x-a`, could nicely result in a new address and `!(x-a)` is 0.  `x==a` will attempt to create a pointer out of `a` which *if* it makes for a valid pointer, code then results in 0 or 1.

---

Code to what conveys the most clarity and leave the micro-optimization concerns to the compiler.

With a *comparison* this is certainly `==`.

---

On a theoretical level, say `!(x-a)` and `x==a` had the same  functionality  for all `a,x`.  If one was faster than the other, a *good* compiler would then emit code based on the faster of the two.

A weaker compiler may benefit with the coder knowing better than the compiler.  [Yeah, right](https://sayingimages.com/wp-content/uploads/yeah-right-surreeee-meme.png)